# Bug in site header leaves a white space gap on the top right when signed in

Tags: bug

This bug happens when you disable the sticky ness for the top navigation bar in your site preferences.

Then, search for any user on the main site or meta logged in as a moderator. I do hide the left nav and this doesn’t happen when I log out. I also hide left nav if you want to reproduce this.

Any user page breaks the layout as do edit history links:

- [links to edit revisions that break layout](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/337222/revisions).
- [here is my user profile breaks layout](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5472/bmike)

Note that every user profile renders broken, this isn’t about one or a few profiles but all user pages on the site. Similarly, every edit revision page is broken, not just the one sample linked above.

The top navigation shows a noticeable white space gap approximately 10% of the width of the page.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Browsers that I can reproduce this are:

- Safari 11 and 12 on macOS 10.13.6
- Safari 12 on macOS 10.14
- Safari on iOS 11.4.1
- Safari on iOS 12.0
- Firefox Focus 7.0.2 on iOS 12.1 with default settings for the browser

I have disabled all content blockers / safari extensions and verified this breaks on multiple networks (work / home / library / coffee shop) and that it’s only when I’m signed in and on a subset of pages like user pages listed.

Comment: What safari version? Same on chrome? How wide is your display?

Comment: Not sure safari on iOS gets a version. The display is iPad wide depending on rotation. The Mac is five different models all with different widths. @JBis

Comment: Also reproduce on a new iPad with Firefox Focus - default settings for that browser on iOS. My best guess is content blocking that browsers are applying is breaking the layout.

Comment: I am pretty sure all browsers on iOS are wrappers of WebKit. So the same thing should happen on all browsers.

Comment: The wikipedia page for it says it uses the deprecated [UIWebView API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview) instead of [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) @JBis - you're correct it's all likely the same renderer and this is now explicitly about content blocking and the site choosing cross site scripting in the fundamental design and how some end users will download what they think is a "browser app" and "see some things break".

Answer (score 2):

I'm not seeing this, with or without left nav hidden. I checked in Safari (11.1.2 (13605.3.8)) and Chrome (68.0.3440.106) on macOS 10.13.6 (17G65).

[image: With Left Nav]

[image: Without Left Nav]

Comment: Wow - thanks for posting. It's super reproducible for me on several machines. I'm not sure if "it's just me" makes it better or worse! I'll go back and check versions again.

Comment: Are you running any script blocker things? NoScript? I have UBO but it doesn't seem to impact Ask Different's rendering.

Comment: I typically used 1Blocker and Adamant - but the new 1BlockerX is so awesome, that’s my only safari extension. Even if I white list this site or turn that off entirely - no blocking, I still get this. Crazy - it’s not something I need fixed if even other mods don’t see it.

Comment: How about top navigation bar stickiness?

Comment: @bmike stickiness is a-okay for me in Firefox, Chrome and Safari for me. Lastest Mojave release.

Comment: Thanks Ian - I have no clue at this point....

Answer (score 1):

Not seen on my account. Maybe something limited to moderator accounts.

---

Not seen Safari 12.0 (macOS Mojave) or Chrome 68.0.3440.75 (macOS Mojave). Not seen on Safari/Chrome Sierra either.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for adding what is clear and what is failing. Turn off left navigation in your user settings and see if that’s the variable. I don’t get the bug when I log out of the site.

Comment: @bmike See edits. Most likely due to you having a mod account. If you give me your user and pass I can check. Jk. Jk.

Comment: I’ll nominate you or bug you to throw your hat in the ring next time we have a moderator election!

Comment: @bmike  Will definitely do!! Thanks :)